# Mapbox gl js contour lines + elevation

Tags: javascript, contour, elevation, mapbox-gl-js

How can we add contour layers with elevation labels to our map? I found this: https://www.mapbox.com/blog/satellite-map-with-contours/ , but it doesn't show how. I also found this: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/toggle-layers/ , but the contour lines have no altitude information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see how we've implemented contour labels on our satellite style by looking at the [style on GitHub](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-styles/blob/1ac5e784907e50c2284c7cc59169ac64ce4e885c/styles/satellite-v7.json#L713-L739).

In short, the pieces you need are

- a source that references the [Mapbox Terrain tileset](https://www.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/mapbox-terrain), which includes a [`contours` layer](https://www.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/mapbox-terrain/#contour).
- a [`symbol` layer](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#layers-symbol) that draws `contours` with a [`text-field` property](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#layout-symbol-text-field) that uses a `{token}`

Comment: Is there a way to display contours at zoom level less than 9? https://www.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/mapbox-terrain/#contour makes it seem like 9 is the lowest zoom level that will show.

Comment: the source defines which zoom level shows corresponding data, so there is no possibility to make it with mapbox terrain. But you still can make your own tileset, defines zoom rule as you wish,  and upload it to mapbox studio

Answer (score 5):

The question was posted a while ago but just because I did it for my project, I share it here:

```
map.addLayer({
  "id": "countour-labels",
  "type": "symbol",
  "source": {
    type: 'vector',
    url: 'mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2'
  },
  "source-layer": "contour",
  'layout': {
    'visibility': 'visible',
    'symbol-placement': 'line',
    'text-field': ['concat', ['to-string', ['get', 'ele']], 'm']
  },
  'paint': {
    'icon-color': '#877b59',
    'icon-halo-width': 1,
    'text-color': '#877b59',
    'text-halo-width': 1
  }
})

map.addLayer({
  "id": "countours",
  "type": "line",
  "source": {
    type: 'vector',
    url: 'mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2'
  },
  "source-layer": "contour",
  'layout': {
    'visibility': 'visible',
    'line-join': 'round',
    'line-cap': 'round'
  },
  'paint': {
    'line-color': '#877b59',
    'line-width': 1
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! This seems to place the labels on top (center) of the elevation lines, is there a way to move the labels so they are not "crossed" by the line, e.g. an offset or something alike?

Comment: Figured it out, we can use `'text-anchor': 'bottom'` on the layer to move the label on top of the contour lines!